# How to remove Warning message in SAS LOG

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Below warning message is being written into the SAS LOG when I Insert a Record into a table

"WARNING: Character expression will be truncated when assigned to character column inputjob"

How can I stop writing this message into the SAS lOG, So my job return code will be 0 instead of 4

```
%MACRO INSDRY(inpdsn);

data _NULL_;

   set DB2TS;
   length jobname $8 jobid $8;
   tiotptr = peek(peek(540)+12);
   jobname = peekc(tiotptr,8);
   jscbptr = peek(peek(540)+180);
   ssibptr = peek(jscbptr+316);
   jobid = peekc(ssibptr+15,5);

   inputjob = jobname || ' ' || "JOB" || jobid;

   call symputx('inputjob',inputjob);

run;

proc sql;
  insert into table
(filename, inputjob)

values
(%sysfunc(quote(&inpdsn)),%sysfunc(quote(&inputjob)));
quit;
%MEND;

do i=1 to f_count;
   set ftp_dir_list point=i nobs=f_count;
   if prxmatch(iPat_RE, trim(dir_file)) > 0 then do;
      iFTP_DSN = dir_file;
      CALL EXECUTE (cats('%INSDRY(',trim(iFTP_DSN),');'));
      incount+1;
      found+1;
   end;
end;
```

Getting the warning message for the column input_job which is defined as 17 digits, value i get is also 17 digits.

I am not getting this warning when I remove the macro.

Comment: Don't insert a value that is longer than the target variable.  Please show the code you are using that triggers the note.  Perhaps you just need to wrap the value being assigned in a SUBSTR() function call?

Comment: Your code is confusing as you have a DO loop that is not part of any data step.  But you are clearing making a string that is longer than 17 characters if JOBID has more than 5 non blank characters.  8+1+3+5 = 17.

Comment: do loop is within Data and I m calling a macro using "Call EXECUTE"

my bad the length of the Jobid is 5, it worked when i updated it to $5 but now i m getting "WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference INPUTJOB not resolved." 

based on the below thread, i have tried to define the variable as global  "call symputx('inputjob',inputjob,'g');" , still no luck 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213992/sas-call-symput-not-working-inside-a-macro-and-before-it-did

Comment: What is the larger problem that this code is trying to solve?  Are you sure there isn't an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any DATA step.  I see a macro definition (which should be the first thing in the code since it is just a definition, not actually an execution).

If you are calling a macro via CALL EXECUTE() make sure to surround at least the %INSDRY with %NRSTR() macro function to prevent SAS from executing the macro when the CALL EXECUTE statement executes.  That will just push the SAS statements the macro generates onto a stack to be executed after the data step ends. Instead you want the macro call itself to be added to the stack so that it will execute after the data step ends.

This is especially true if the macro references macro variables whose values are changed by the SAS code that the macro generates.  In your case the CALL SYMPUTX() statement. So when the macro is trying generate the code using the macro variable its value is not yet set because the statements that will set its value are still waiting to run.

So the program flow should be something like this:

```
%MACRO INSDRY(inpdsn);
... body of the macro definition here ...
%MEND;

data _null_;
   set ftp_dir_list ; 
   if prxmatch(iPat_RE, trim(dir_file)) then do;
      iFTP_DSN = dir_file;
      CALL EXECUTE(cats('%nrstr(%INSDRY)(',iFTP_DSN,')'));
      incount+1;
      found+1;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you Tom, it worked after changing the execute as above

Answer (score 0):

`JobName` and `JobId` are both $8, so the concatenation assignment statement

```
inputjob = jobname || ' ' || "JOB" || jobid;
```

will implicitly create variable `inputjob` of length `$20`.

Remove `"JOB"` from the concatenation and you will be at `$17`.

Many times it is best to code a `length` or `attrib` statement at the start of the step to ensure you explicitly define variables in the PDV.